# How to include/not include external Javascript files according on the device (e.g. Desktop, mobile, etc?

Tags: javascript

I have this code on my header (I know sort of bad practice):

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.expander.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/custom.js"></script>

</head>
```

I don't want to include this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script>
```

on mobile and tablet. Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no 100% safe solution to detect mobile devices :

- UA sniffing depends on a list of mobile UA. Those lists are quite up to date, but can't handle the future/rare devices.
- feature detection is quite hard when the criteria is as broad as "mobile/tablet". Screen resolution is not anymore so different between non mobile and mobile (check the new Google Phone, better res than a netbook), touch support can be found in classic lcd screens...

I would go for a php UA sniffing solution based on WURFL, without redirect : if not mobile, echo your script, if mobile, echo a nothing.

But the mobile and non mobile world are merging. You should use feature detection to check for the support of specifics features you want to use, whether it's a mobile or a non mobile device.

Check http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/ for a simple UA sniffing in php

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do this but this is the solution:
Use javascript to decide if its a mobile accessing your site or a computer...

Then if its a mobile, redirect the user to the mobile page without that JS code...

If its not redirect to the computer page...

You'll have to create separate pages to do that...

I'm sure there may be other ways to do this too...

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate/blob/master/public/index.html

include different files for production and tester ENV

```
 // Mobile/Desktop Detection script
            (function(ua, w, d, undefined) {

                // App Environment
                // ---------------
                //  Tip: Set to true to turn on "production" mode
                var production = true,
                        filesToLoad,
                //BoilerplateMVC Helper Methods
                        boilerplateMVC = {
                            loadCSS: function(url, callback) {
                                var link = d.createElement("link");
                                link.type = "text/css";
                                link.rel = "stylesheet";
                                link.href = url;
                                d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
                                if(callback) {
                                    callback();
                                }
                            },
                            loadJS: function(file, callback) {
                                var script = d.createElement("script");
                                script.type = "text/javascript";
                                if (script.readyState) {  // IE
                                    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                        if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                                            script.onreadystatechange = null;
                                            callback();
                                        }
                                    };
                                } else {  // Other Browsers
                                    script.onload = function() {
                                        callback();
                                    };
                                }
                                if(((typeof file).toLowerCase()) === "object" && file["data-main"] !== undefined) {
                                    script.setAttribute("data-main", file["data-main"]);
                                    script.async = true;
                                    script.src = file.src;
                                } else {
                                    script.src = file;
                                }
                                d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
                            },
                            loadFiles: function(production, obj, callback) {
                                var self = this;
                                if(production) {
                                    // Loads the production CSS file(s)
                                    self.loadCSS(obj["prod-css"], function() {
                                        // If there are production JavaScript files to load
                                        if(obj["prod-js"]) {
                                            // Loads the correct initialization file (which includes Almond.js)
                                            self.loadJS(obj["prod-js"], callback);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    // Loads the development CSS file(s)
                                    self.loadCSS(obj["dev-css"], function() {
                                        // If there are development Javascript files to load
                                        if(obj["dev-js"]) {
                                            // Loads Require.js and tells Require.js to find the correct intialization file
                                            self.loadJS(obj["dev-js"], callback);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        };

                // Mobile/Tablet Logic
                if((/iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|IEMobile/).test(ua)) {

                    // Mobile/Tablet CSS and JavaScript files to load
                    filesToLoad = {
                        // CSS file that is loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-css": "css/mobile.css",
                        // CSS file that is loaded when in production mode
                        "prod-css": "css/mobile.min.css",
                        // Require.js configuration file that is loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-js": { "data-main": "js/app/config/config.js", "src": "js/libs/require.js" },
                        // JavaScript initialization file that is also loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-init": "js/app/init/MobileInit.js",
                        // JavaScript file that is loaded when in production mode
                        "prod-init": "js/app/init/MobileInit.min.js",
                        "prod-js": { "data-main": "js/app/config/config.js", "src": "js/libs/require.js" }
                    };

                }

                // Desktop Logic
                else {

                    // Desktop CSS and JavaScript files to load
                    filesToLoad = {
                        // CSS file that is loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-css": "css/desktop.css",
                        // CSS file that is loaded when in production mode
                        "prod-css": "css/desktop.min.css",
                        // Require.js configuration file that is also loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-js": { "data-main": "js/app/config/config.js", "src": "js/libs/require.js" },
                        // JavaScript initialization file that is loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-init": "js/app/init/DesktopInit.js",
                        // JavaScript file that is loaded when in production mode
                        "prod-init": "js/app/init/DesktopInit.min.js",
                        "prod-js": { "data-main": "js/app/config/config.js", "src": "js/libs/require.js" }
                    };

                }

                boilerplateMVC.loadFiles(production, filesToLoad, function() {
                    if(!production && window.require) {
                        require([filesToLoad["dev-init"]]);
                    } else if ( production ) {
                        require([filesToLoad["prod-init"]])
                    }
                });

            })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, window, document);
```